# Replacing the values of an RDD with another

Tags: scala, apache-spark, rdd

I have two data sets like below. Each data set has "," separated numbers in each line.

> **Dataset 1**
>
> 1,2,0,8,0
>
> 2,0,9,0,3
>
> **Dataset 2**
>
> 7,5,4,6,3
>
> 4,9,2,1,8

I have to replace the zeroes of the first data set with the corresponding values from the data set 2.

So the result would look like this

> 1,2,4,8,3
>
> 2,9,9,1,3

I replaced the values with the code below.

```
val rdd1 = sc.textFile(dataset1).flatMap(l => l.split(","))
val rdd2 = sc.textFile(dataset2).flatMap(l => l.split(","))
val result = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map( x => if(x._1 == "0") x._2 else x._1)
```

The output I got is of the format  **RDD[String]**. But I need the output in the format **RDD[Array[String]]** as this format would be more suitable for my further transformations.

Comment: Are you looking for something like `val result = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(x => if(x._1 == "0") Array(x._2) else Array(x._1))`?

Comment: @AlexisC. No. The rdd1 and rdd2 are of type RDD[Array[String]]. So x._1 in your code refers to the array

Comment: Well it's not clear from your snippet. You are flat mapping after splitting, resulting in a `RDD[String]` and doing `x._1 == "0"`; so how `x._1` can refer to an array? Unless you want a `RDD[Array[String]]` with 2 arrays (one for each line) ?

Comment: Sorry for not being very clear. I wanted a result RDD of type RDD[Array[String]] with 2 arrays (one for each line) . But, the code I wrote gives the result in the format RDD[String] as I used flatMap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want an `RDD[Array[String]]`, where each element of the array correspond to a line, don't flat map the values after splitting, just map them.

```
scala> val rdd1 = sc.parallelize(List("1,2,0,8,0", "2,0,9,0,3")).map(l => l.split(","))
rdd1: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at map at <console>:27

scala> val rdd2 = sc.parallelize(List("7,5,4,6,3", "4,9,2,1,8")).map(l => l.split(","))
rdd2: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at map at <console>:27

scala> val result = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map{case(arr1, arr2) => arr1.zip(arr2).map{case(v1, v2) => if(v1 == "0") v2 else v1}}
result: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[5] at map at <console>:31

scala> result.collect
res0: Array[Array[String]] = Array(Array(1, 2, 4, 8, 3), Array(2, 9, 9, 1, 3))
```

or maybe less verbose:

```
val result = rdd1.zip(rdd2).map(t => t._1.zip(t._2).map(x => if(x._1 == "0") x._2 else x._1))
```

Comment: I have another RDD which has the threshold values for the above result in the format Array(Array(6, 100), Array(5, 100), Array(7, 100), Array(0, 100), Array(-1, 100)). How do I check if the values in each Array of the result RDD are in between these threshold values?